# Async call update HTML Element though Angular 4.x Service

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Trying to update a HTML element between components use an angular service doesn't seem to work for me.

This is not a duplication of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

Full project: https://github.com/flamusdiu/micro-blog/tree/dev

I have this service:

```
import { ElementRef, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MdSidenav } from '@angular/material';
import { AsyncSubject } from 'rxjs/AsyncSubject ';

import { Article } from '../models/article';

@Injectable ()
export class InterModuleService {
    private _article: AsyncSubject <Article> = new AsyncSubject();      
    public sidenav: MdSidenav;
    public sidenavToc: ElementRef;
}
```

I have placed my observable here. The observable is filled through an Angular Resolver for my route. The component is setup as:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute }   from '@angular/router';

import { Article } from '../../models/article';
import { InterModuleService } from '../../service/inter-module.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-article-detail',
  templateUrl: './article-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./article-detail.component.css']
})
export class ArticleDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  private article: Article;

  constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute, private interModuleService: InterModuleService ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.data
        .subscribe((data: { article: Article } ) => {
            this.interModuleService.article.next(data.article);
        });

    this.interModuleService.article
        .subscribe((data) => {
            this.article = data;
            this.interModuleService.sidenavToc.nativeElement['innerHTML'] = data.toc;
        });
  }
}
```

I get this is some sort of Async problem. I get the article data which updates the view just find. However, any property of the article object is always "undefined" or "null" when read at any point which makes me thing my method of trying to do this is not completely right.

---

If I add some console.logs like this:

```
this.interModuleService.article.take(1)
        .subscribe((data) => {
            this.article = data;
            console.log(this.article);
            console.log(this.article.toc);
            this.interModuleService.sidenavToc.nativeElement['innerHTML'] = data.toc;
        });
```

I get the follow screenshot (ignore the HTML formatting issues):

[image: screencap of issue]

---

Just for reference: `article.toc` is shorthand for `article.attachments['toc']['data']`. However, referencing this directly yields the same result as above. `article.attachments['toc']` has data but the property `data` is undefined when called.

---

Changed from `BehaviorSubject` to `AsyncSubject` since I only really care about the last one emitted. Probably should not expose the Subject but didn't see a good way to not do that. Though `data.toc` is still undefined. =(

Comment: Please give a [mcve]; where are those undefineds appearing, and how is this rendered in the template?

Comment: `this.interModuleService.sidenavToc.nativeElement['innerHTML'] = data.toc` is always `undefined` and just pushes 'undefined' to the template. Now, `data` isn't undefined and contains the information of course.

Comment: Have you logged `data` inside that callback? Or in the previous subscription where you extract `.article` from it?

Comment: Yes, if I was to do `console.log(this.article)` gives me the object. However, doing `console.log(this.article.toc)` gives me undefined even though on the console I can clearly see the property 'toc' has data. Leads me to believe an async issue of some sort.

Comment: Added screen shot from doing the console.logs(). =)

Comment: You should not directly expose the subject. Instead, allow updates to pushed _through_ the service.

Comment: Umm, true. What way should I do that?

Comment: @AluanHaddad updated code, like that?

Comment: Sure I guess that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to move the whole async process of getting the attachments closer to where I needed it for some reason. I am still unsure of the reason for doing this other then something to do with the way Async processes resolve and expecting a value that might come at any point needs to be accounted for.

Here is the working code:

**inter-module.service.ts**:

```
import { ElementRef, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MdSidenav } from '@angular/material';
import { AsyncSubject } from 'rxjs/AsyncSubject';

import { Article } from '../models/article';

@Injectable ()
export class InterModuleService {
    public article: AsyncSubject<Article> = new AsyncSubject();

    public sidenav: MdSidenav;
    public sidenavToc: ElementRef;  
}
```

**article-detail.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute }   from '@angular/router';

import { Article } from '../../models/article';

import { ArticleStore } from '../../state/ArticleStore';
import { InterModuleService } from '../../service/inter-module.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-article-detail',
  templateUrl: './article-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./article-detail.component.css']
})
export class ArticleDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  private article: Article;

  constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute, 
               private articleStore: ArticleStore,
               private interModuleService: InterModuleService ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.interModuleService.article
        .subscribe((data) => {
            this.article = data;

            Promise.all(Object.keys(this.article['attachments']).map((at) => {
                return this.articleStore.getAttachment(this.article['id'],at).then ((res) => {
                    this.article.attachments[at]['data'] = res.toString();
                })
            })).then(()=> {
                this.interModuleService.sidenavToc.nativeElement['innerHTML'] = this.article.attachments['toc'].data;
            });

        });
    this.route.data
        .subscribe((data: { article: Article } ) => {
            this.interModuleService.article.next(data.article);
            this.interModuleService.article.complete();
        });
  }
}
```

**article-detail.resolver.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, Resolve, RouterStateSnapshot, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Article } from '../../models/article';
import { ArticleStore } from '../../state/ArticleStore';


@Injectable()
export class ArticleDetailResolver implements Resolve<Article> {

  constructor(private articleStore: ArticleStore, private router: Router) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<Article> {

    let id = route.params['id'];

    return this.articleStore.getArticle(id).then(article => {
      if (article) {
        return new Article(article);

      } else { // id not found
        this.router.navigate(['/articles']);
        return null;
      }
    });
  }
}
```